# Check which element is ":active" in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know that `:foucus` and `:active` are different states and if you click an `<input>` element it becomes activated AND focused, but if you click somewhere else in the page it stops being activated (the cursor stops appearing) but keeps being focused unless another focusable element has been focused

I want an input element to disappear when it stops being *activated* but I don't know how to do this since I see that the variable `document.activeElement` only targets the currently focused element, not the currently activated one

I know if I had a variable like `document.activeElement` and a function like `focus()` for the *activated* state I could implement what I want, but I don't know if it is possible since I don't know if these variable and function exist

Comment: "I want an input element to disappear when it stops being activated " Why not just use CSS for this?

Comment: Because the only way that I've found that makes my inputs *activated* when appearing for the first time is `autoFocus`, and that would not work for the second time they appear if I only make them dissapear with css

Comment: Additionally I want other elements to appear when my `<input>` element dissapear, so I need Javascript to listen to this event which in the case of `:focus` I can do using the `focusin` event

Comment: Your first paragraph is all wrong. An focusable element gains the focus when you click on it and loses the focus when you click elsewhere, or tab out (and in a few other circumstances). An element is `:active:` only while it is being clicked on (or a trigger key, usually Enter, is pressed while it is focused), it loses the active state when the mouse button (or key) is released. Do you actually want to track the active and focus state or do you want to track the states you described and misattributed?

Comment: Show your code and the expected result.

Comment: @Quentin This solved answered my question